# How to use gohook to bind right and other buttons?

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    hook "github.com/robotn/gohook"
)

func main() {

    // out: alt-q
    hook.Register(hook.KeyDown, []string{"alt", "q"}, func(e hook.Event) {
        fmt.Println("alt-q")
    })

    // out: no output
    hook.Register(hook.KeyDown, []string{"up"}, func(e hook.Event) {
        fmt.Println("up")
    })

    // out: no output
    hook.Register(hook.KeyHold, []string{"left"}, func(e hook.Event) {
        fmt.Println("left")
    })

    // out: no output
    hook.Register(hook.KeyUp, []string{"down"}, func(e hook.Event) {
        fmt.Println("down")
    })

    s := hook.Start()
    <-hook.Process(s)
}
```

I didn't find the relevant instructions, how to use it?

=================================================

I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the keyboard, the following code prints out the keys normally

```golang
hook.Register(hook.KeyUp, []string{}, func(e hook.Event) {
    fmt.Println(e)
})
```

Thank you for your attention.